# What can be done to solve this error. Please help me out

Tags: jsp, using

```
<code><html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.io.*"%>

  <%   
   Connection conn= null;   
    //Statement stmt= null;
    Statement stmt2= null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
            int sno=0,c=0;  
            String tsno;
            int cform=0;

            String fc=(String)session.getAttribute("fclass");
            String fy=(String)session.getAttribute("fyear");
            //String srno=(String)hs.getValue("srlno");
            String sid1=(String)session.getAttribute("sid");
            String spwd1=(String)session.getAttribute("spwd");
            //String shat2=(String)hs.getValue("shat");

            System.out.println("update = "+sid1);
//          System.out.println("update = "+spwd);
//          System.out.println("update = "+shat2);
            sno=c;
            int shat=0;

                if( sid1==null || spwd1==null || sno==0)
                {
                 sid1  = request.getParameter("tsid2");
                 System.out.println(sid1);
                 spwd1= request.getParameter("tspwd2");
                 fc   = request.getParameter("tclass");
                 fy   = request.getParameter("tyear");
                 tsno  = request.getParameter("tc");
                 sno=Integer.parseInt(tsno);    
                }



            int i=0, k=0;
// Previous Form 
                    String ht02="g2",ht03="g3",ht04="g4",ht05="g5",ht06="g6",ht07="g7",ht08="g8",ht09="g9";//,ht10="g10",ht11="g11",ht12="g12",ht13="g13";
// New  form
                    String ft2,ft3,ft4,ft5,ft6,ft7,ft8,ft9;//ft10,ft11,ft12,ft13;

                    int gt4,gt5,gt6,gt7,gt8,gt9;//,gt10,gt11,gt12,gt13;
                    String fs=new String("y");
                    int up=0;
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------                            

                            try
                            {
                                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:aec","Vinayaka","Vinayaka");

                                stmt2=conn.createStatement();
                                String Sq="select   *From STUDENTS_INFO where STUDENTID='"+sid1+"' and PWD='"+spwd1+"' ";

                                rs = stmt2.executeQuery(Sq);

                                while(rs.next())
                                {   
                                if (fs.equals(rs.getString("FORMSUBMITT")))
                                {
                                    System.out.println(" Status in get"+fs);
                                    up=1;
                                    response.sendRedirect("errorpage.html");
                                }

                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e2){
                            e2.printStackTrace();}
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            if (up==0 && sid1!=null)
            {
            while (k<sno)
            {           System.out.println("This loop in"+i+"times"+" "+sid1);
                        ht02="ht02+i"; ht03=ht03+i; ht04=ht04+i; ht05=ht05+i; ht06=ht06+i;
                        ht07=ht07+i; ht08=ht08+i; ht09=ht09+i;// ht10=ht10+i; ht11=ht11+i; ht12=ht12+i; ht13=ht13+i;


                        ft2 = request.getParameter(ht02); ft3 = request.getParameter(ht03); ft4 = request.getParameter(ht04);
                        ft5 = request.getParameter(ht05); ft6 = request.getParameter(ht06); ft7 = request.getParameter(ht07);
                        ft8 = request.getParameter(ht08); ft9 = request.getParameter(ht09); /*ft10 = req.getParameter(ht10);
                        ft11 = req.getParameter(ht11);ft12 = req.getParameter(ht12);ft13 = req.getParameter(ht13);*/

                        gt4=Integer.parseInt(ft4); gt5=Integer.parseInt(ft5); gt6=Integer.parseInt(ft6);
                        gt7=Integer.parseInt(ft7); gt8=Integer.parseInt(ft8); gt9=Integer.parseInt(ft9);
                        /*gt10=Integer.parseInt(ft10); gt11=Integer.parseInt(ft11); gt12=Integer.parseInt(ft12);
                        gt13=Integer.parseInt(ft13);*/
                        float tot=((float)(gt4+gt5+gt6+gt7+gt8+gt9))/6;

                         try
                            {
                                stmt2=conn.createStatement();   

                                    stmt2.executeUpdate( "Insert into SUB_DET values("+i+",'"+ft3+"','"+ft2+"','"+fc+"','"+fy+"',"+gt4+","+gt5+","+gt6+","+gt7+","+gt8+","+gt9+","+tot+")");    
                                    response.sendRedirect("logout.html");


                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();}
            i=i+1;
            }
                            try
                            {


                                    stmt2.executeUpdate("update STUDENTS_INFO set formsubmitt='"+fs+"' where STUDENTID='"+sid1+"' and pwd='"+spwd1+"' ");  
                                    cform=1;

                            }
                            catch(Exception e1){
                            e1.printStackTrace();}





                    /*try
                            {
                                if(sid!=null)
                                {
                                    stmt2=conn.createStatement();   
                                    stmt2.executeUpdate("update STUDENTS_INFO set formsubmitt='"+fs+"' where STUDENTID='"+sid+"' and pwd='"+spwd+"' ");  
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();}*/
                    if(rs!=null)
                    {
                     rs.close();
                     System.out.println("Feed  back rs is Closed");
                    }


                    if(stmt2!=null)
                    {
                     stmt2.close();
                     System.out.println("Feed  back statement is Closed");
                    }

                    if(conn!=null)
                    {
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("Feed back update Connection2 Closed");
                    }
            }



                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    System.out.println("tinku");
                }



%>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

**where this is the error :**

```
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 229 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected

An error occurred at line: 231 in the generated java file
out cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 231 in the generated java file
_jspx_out cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 232 in the generated java file
out cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 232 in the generated java file
out cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 233 in the generated java file
out cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 234 in the generated java file
_jspx_page_context cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 234 in the generated java file
_jspx_page_context cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 236 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token "finally", { expected

An error occurred at line: 237 in the generated java file
_jspx_page_context cannot be resolved

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Your question is really long. Post a small sample which illustrates your problem

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title

Answer (score 1):

comment `finally
                    {
                    System.out.println("tinku");
                }`

it will work

Comment: As I read the code, you have to remove the closing brace before the finally {} block as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why Java code should not be put in JSPs. Use a servlet for Java code, and only use the EL, the JSTL and other JSP tags in the JSPs, whose sole purpose should be to generate HTML markup.

When Java code is in a servlet, it's precompiled, and your IDE helps you identify and fix the compilation issues. The IDE will also help you formatting and indenting your Java code in order to make it readable.